# getResource() и JAR файл

Tags: java, jar, project, main

Есть проект, который замечательно запускается в IDEA, но при создании jar файла и его запуска вылетает исключение Location is not set

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at by.nick.main.Main.showAuthorization(Main.java:42)
at by.nick.main.Main.start(Main.java:34)
```

Вот сама функция, вызывающая ошибку:

```
public void showAuthorization(){

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../authorization/view/AuthorizationView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane=(AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        AuthorizationViewController controller=loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);
        controller.setStage(stage);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В манифесте прописано всё правильно:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: by.nick.main.Main

Я уже сломал голову! :(

Comment: Относительные пути, увы, не работают при создании runnable jar. Используйте абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, при обращении к ресурсам внутри JAR не поддерживается синтаксис `./` и `../`. Вам надо или использовать абсолютный путь:

```
Main.class.getResource("/by/nick/authorization/view/AuthorizationView.fxml")
```

или найти/написать библиотеку, которая преобразует относительный путь в абсолютный.